# Como obtener una respuesta de un php a angular

Tags: php, mysql, angular, typescript

Tengo un problema que es que cuando ejecuto mi archivo php me retorna un json y quiero que esta respuesta la use angular. Pero no me la lee.
Este seria el archivo php:

```
<?php
try{
 $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba','root','');       
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "Error" . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$productos =  $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos");
$productos->execute();
$productos = $productos->fetchAll();

$userData = array();
foreach ($productos as $producto) {
    $userData['AllUsers'][] = $producto;
}
echo json_encode($userData);
?>
```

Y este seria el service que lo usaría:

```
constructor( public http: HttpClient ) { 
    console.log('listo');
    this.listar();
}
private listar(){
  this.http.get('assets/api/productos.php') //info.json funciona y tiene el mismo contenido 
     .subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

´El problema se solucionó habilitando un segundo servidor´

Quisiera saber como haría para subirlo a un hosting, solo deberia hacer un "ng build --prod"? porque como puse a un "localhost:1234" a escuchar los archivos php.

Comment: Hola Anthony! Qué muestra la consola? console.log(data);

Answer (score 2):

Mira, lo que yo procuro realizar en mis proyectos con Angular es lo siguiente para obtener los datos de una Base de Datos:

**Ejemplo PHP**

```
<?php

  //Declaracion de cabeceras del sistema
  header("Context-type: application/json;");
  //Inclusion del archivo respectivo para la conexion con la BD
  require '../conexion.php';
  //Declaracion del array para codificar en formato JSON la variable mensaje
  $resultado = array();
  //Evaluamos si la conexion a la BD se realiza correctamente
  if ($mysqli)
  {
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    $resultadoConsulta = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM productos");

    $data = array();

    while ($row = $resultadoConsulta->fetch_assoc())
    {
      $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
  }
  else
  {
    //Para obtener el resultado de la variable $resultado tienes que hacer algo mas en Angular.
    $resultado['mensaje'] = "Problema de conexión";

    echo json_encode($resultado);
  }

 ?>
```

Ya teniendo verificado los datos por parte del servidor, podemos proseguir con realizar las respectivas peticiones al servidor para obtener y procesar dichos datos:

> **Nota:** Es recomendable utilizar servicios para obtener una mayor estructura de las funciones y metodos. Esto a modo de recomendación para las personas que lleguen hasta aquí.

Utilizamos el comando: `ng generate service services/nombrearchivo`, cuando hago referencia a `services` es al nombre de la carpeta, puede ser `cualquiercosa`, esto para una mayor facilidad de estructurar tus archivos.

**Angular - Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConsultaComunService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //Declaramos la funcion para recuperar los datos procesados por el constructor de la clase
  public obtenerProductos()
  {
    return new Promise(
      resolve=>{
        this.http.get('url.php')
        .subscribe(
        data => resolve(data)
        )
      }
    )
  };
}
```

**Angular - Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input  } from '@angular/core';
//Importacion de servicios
import { InventarioService } from './../services/nombrearchivo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-producto',
  templateUrl: './producto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./producto.component.css']
})

export class ProductoComponent implements OnInit {
  //Variables donde se almacenan los datos obtenidos por el servicio
  listadoProducto:any;
  productos:any;
constructor(private _serviceProducto:ConsultaProductoService)
  {

    //Recuperar los datos del servicio para obtener los productos.
    _serviceComun.obtenerImpuesto()
    .then(data=>{
      this.listadoProducto = data;
      this.cargarProductos();
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });


  };

//Preparamos la funcion para obtener el listado de los productos
  cargarProductos()
  {
    this.productos = this.listadoProductos;
    //Evaluamos si el listado obtenido cuenta con registros, con la finalidad de hacerle saber al usuario que no cuenta con registros.
    if (this.categorias.length > 0)
    {
      this.mensajeSinProductos = false;
    }
    else
    {
      this.mensajeSinProductos = true;
    }
  };
}
```

**Vista**

Ya en esta parte solo tienes que recorrer los datos con la directiva de angular `*ngFor`:

`*ngFor="let producto of productos"`.

> **Para tener en cuenta:**

1. Te recomiendo habilitar un segundo servidor(que se mantenga escuchando todo el tiempo) para poder ejecutar los archivos de PHP, lo que procuro realizar es usar el comando `php -S 0.0.0.0:1234`, obviamente, tienes que ir hasta la ruta donde tengas tus archivos PHP que creo que es en la carpeta `assets/api`.
2. Puedes usar xampp para habilitar tus Bases de datos y a la cual puedas hacer el respectivo CRUD.
3. Declara muy bien todos tus modelos, tanto en la vista como en tu componente de typescript, porque al momento de enviarlo a producción tendrás ciertos problemas si no lo haces.
4. Y por ultimo, debes de crear un archivo llamado: `proxyconfig.json` en la misma division del `package.json`
5. El contenido ha de ser el siguiente:

   {
        "/authentication": {
             "target": "http://localhost:1234",
             "secure": false,
             "changeOrigin": true
          }
     }
6. Modificamos el archivo package.json en la linea 6 por la siguiente instruccion: `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json",` posteriormente utilizas el comando `ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json` para iniciar los servicios de angular.

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Gracias jecorrales, comparto la solución. La solución estaba en levantar el otro servidor "http://localhost:1234" para que este atento a los archivos .php

Comment: Quisiera saber como haría para subirlo a un hosting, solo deberia hacer un "ng build --prod"? porque como puse un "localhost:1234" no creo que vaya a leer eso el hosting. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Hola @AnthonyDC , que bueno que te haya servido parte de mi respuesta. Para enviar tu servicio a producción solo debes hacer uso del comando `ng build --prod`, ello te genera un archivo en el directorio `dist` que crea los servicios de produccion por medio de `angular cli`. No debes preocuparte del hosting, por si solo debes de subir a tu hosting lo que hay dentro del contenido del directorio que te mencioné anteriormente, y subir correctamente los ficheros de `php` que coincidan respectivamente con las direcciones a las que apuntas por medio de los métodos de cada servicio.

Comment: Si tienes alguna otra duda te puedo colaborar, y si te sirvio parte de mi respuesta te recomiendo que la marques como la respuesta que solucionó tu pregunta. Esto con mejorar y mantener los protocolos de la comunidad. Gracias!